# How give an auto wired inside a @Spy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

Actually I have the following problem:

I have a Test which need the real call from the service.

```
class ServiceATest{

@Spy serviceNeedRealValue service;

//other beans mocked there...

@InjectMocks private serviceA serviceA;

//The test method...

}
```

Well my problem comes, when I call the `service` because the service have an autowired bean which give me a null pointer, and I don't know how inject or tell to him is a mock.

```
class serviceNeedRealValue {

@Autowired aThingWhichDontNeedARealBehaivour thing;

// some methods...

}
```

So actually I need mock the `aThingWhichDontNeedARealBehaivour` but I don't know how. I tried to use an `@Autowired` on the `@Spy` service or try to inject mock on there but nothing works so I don't have more ideas about that.

P.D. I know the situation not the correct but actually I need the Spy service because I need check the data (its related with hashing, so I can't create a simulated behavior)

Comment: Plain Spring or are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Spring Boot @M.Deinum

Comment: Write a test using Spring Boot and use `@SpyBean`.

Comment: Is this a unit test or integration test?  If unit, why _which need the real call from the service_?

Comment: Checking other post in Stack I see that solution but when I try to apply the service give me a null... @M.Deinum

Comment: Actually its a mix because I need check the behavior of one method but I need the data of the hashing for that situation @AndrewS

Comment: `@SpyBean` needs to be used in conjucting with `@SpringBootTest` or one of the sliced test `@WebMvcTest` etc. else it won't work. Also why wouldn't you be able use a mock, combined with an `ArgumentCaptor` (assuming it is something passed into the object) you are perfectly capable of doing the validation.

Comment: Actually with the @SpringBootTest works perfectly, but I am interested in that other solution, you have a link about how use the argument captor. And of course if you want put your answer as a "answer" for close and give you the +. Really thank you